# awk split a fixed width file into different files using the dates in it and keep the header

Tags: awk

I have this awk command that splits the file based on the date inside it. But it does not keep the header. How do I keep the header and put the .txt extension? Thank you.

Here's some sample lines:

> HEADER    00000000000019011600000    0000000EA
>   000000000000000PRODUCT1 (EA) 00000000000020011600000    0000000EA
>   000000000000000PRODUCT2 (EA) 00000000000021011600000    0000000EA
>   000000000000000PRODUCT3

here's the command I'm using:

```
"{fn=substr($0,13,6);print >  substr($0,17,2) substr($0,15,2) substr($0,13,2) }" D:\myfiletosplit.txt
```

current output:

file 1

```
filename: 160119   
inside the file: 00000000000019011600000    0000000EA   000000000000000PRODUCT1 (EA)
```

file 2

```
filename: 160120  
inside the file:00000000000020011600000    0000000EA   000000000000000PRODUCT2 (EA)
```

file 3

```
filename: 160121  
inside the file: 00000000000021011600000    0000000EA   000000000000000PRODUCT3
```

expected output:

file1

```
filename: 160119.txt  
inside file:   
HEADER  
00000000000019011600000 0000000EA 000000000000000PRODUCT1 (EA)
```

file 2

```
filename: 160120.txt  
inside the file:  
HEADER  
00000000000020011600000    0000000EA   000000000000000PRODUCT2 (EA)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[^0-9]/ {h=$0; next}                   # save header in var h
{ f=gensub(/(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})/,"\\3\\2\\1.txt","g",substr($0,13,6))   
                                         # save filename in f
  if (!a[f]++) print h > f;              # if not seen f, print header to f
  print $0 >> f;                         # print line to file f
  close(f)
}
```

Call this with:

```
awk -f tst.awk input.txt
```

or with oneliner:

```
awk '/^[^0-9]/ {h=$0; next} { f=gensub(/(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})/, "\\3\\2\\1.txt","g",substr($0,13,6));if (!a[f]++) print h > f;print $0 >> f;close(f)}' input.txt
```

and for our windows users (escaping horror):

```
awk "/^[^0-9]/ {h=$0; next} { f=gensub(/(..)(..)(..)/,\"C:\\\\Users\\\\Marc\\\\Documents\\\\\\3\\2\\1.txt\",\"g\",substr($0,13,6));if (!a[f]++) print h > f;print $0 >> f;close(f)}" C:\Users\Marc\Documents\input.txt
```

Comment: please `close(f)` as well to avoid `too many files open` error,   `print $0 >>f; close(f);`

Comment: Hi Marc - I tried your one liner and getting 'backslash not last character on line' error. I am running this in windows.

Comment: Hi Marc, I removed the "%s.txt"  part and it worked but obviously without the .txt extension. What can I replace it with? I tried replacing single quote (')  and didn't work either. I can just rename the files also but was trying to eliminate manual intervention.

Comment: Added windows oneliner to answer.

Comment: hi Marc - the windows version didn't work. I get unterminated string in the double quote after f=sprintf.

Comment: I am accepting the answer because removing the "%s.txt" part worked. I will just rename the created files to put the extension .txt. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've used this exact string in cmd.exe and it works. How are you using it?

Comment: Hi Mark - I put it in a .bat file. Must be something in there as I've tried in the command line and it did work. I just realized that my original command create the file with the yymmdd date format. Any chance this can be done too? So it sorts the files in order.

Comment: Regarding the quotes: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php. Regarding the date format: you mean you want ddmmyy converted to yymmdd.txt?

Comment: Yes. I have now edited the expected output in my post.

Comment: Adapted the awk calls with a gensub call. Windows version will be a escaping horror.

Comment: Standard advice for Windows users - put the script in a file and execute is as `awk -f script` to avoid the quoting nightmare or better yet install cygwin and run awk from that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the header is in the first line, you can read the first line, and then read the rest separately.

```
awk 'NR == 1 { header = $0 } NR > 1 { fn=substr($0,13,6); print header"\n" $0 > (fn".txt") }' input.txt
```

If you run that for your example, it will output what you want.

Comment: This will print var header for every line where NR > 1

Comment: Hi Klaus, thank you for responding. I am getting an error "backslash not last character on line". I've tried change to '' but getting invalid char instead. Any idea why this is? thank you.

Comment: This will read first line and save it to variable 'header'. For all other lines it will save the substring you want to 'fn' and output the header together with the whole line to the file named 'fn'.txt.

I think that you are using windows, then try to replace header"\n" $0 with header ORS $0

Comment: It printed the header after each line, not on top only. I compressed the sample data but there are more than 1 line per date.